# bytebuddy: annotate already builded class

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have super class and some childs of this superclass.
I need annotate superclass as @XmlSeeAlso, that require as param array of child classes.
But for create childs classes, i need loaded super, that not build yet. 
Having circle dependency.
It is possible, that build all classes without this annotation, and annotate after that? as next phase, when all classes available, but not annotated?

```
@XmlSeeAlso(value = {ExtFoo.class, ExtFoo1.class})
class Foo {
    //...
}

class ExtFoo extends Foo {
    //..
}

class ExtFoo1 extends Foo {
    //...
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .annotateType(new XmlSeeAlso(){

                @Override
                public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                    return XmlSeeAlso.class;
                }

                @Override
                public Class[] value() {
                    return new Class[0];//how to get childs of foo classes, when self foo not ready???
                }
            }).make().load(...);
            ....;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AnnotationDescription.Builder and use TypeDescriptions to represent the types. You can use a TypePool.Default to resolve these descriptions.